# What is a proper use-case of `std::nullptr_t` template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

Today I came to know that C++ allows non-type template parameters of type `std::nullptr_t`:

```
template<std::nullptr_t N> struct A { };

template<std::nullptr_t N> void f() { }
```

For the life of me, I cannot come up with any sensible use-case for these. Can anyone please come up with a rationale for this?

Comment: I don't think there is a use-case, *but* there's not enough harm in allowing it to be worth the trouble of stopping it from happening. If you did stop it, you'd have to either decide that nullptr_t wasn't a type at all, *or* you'd have to create a special case to say it's not a type allowed as a template parameter (and do the same in the compiler to stop its use).

Comment: What rationale do you mean?  The rational for it being allowed?

Comment: that's what I was thinking.. principle of least astonishment. and there were other stuff in the standard for which originally nobody could come up with a use case, but later it became useful.

Comment: @JerryCoffin there is an explicit list of types allowed as template parameters. So currently there is a special case to say that it is allowed as a template parameter.

Comment: @VaughnCato yes, please. please improve my wording to make it clearer. apparently I failed in doing so.

Comment: I think the rationale would be that only the types of compile-time constants are allowed to be non-type template parameters, and since nullptr is a compile-time constant, the type of nullptr needs to be allowed as a template parameter.

Comment: Not that I dislike this question personally, but the FAQ *does* say *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."*... so should this be closed?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Possibly -- what would be a good place for questions like this?  I would certainly like to visit that site.

Comment: @VaughnCato: I have no idea (maybe Programmers.SE, maybe not?) but I've seen tons of questions like this closed on SO...

Comment: @Mehrdad in what point does my question violate this? Practical: Search for a use case. Answerable: Someone found a rationale because they added it to the Standard. Based on the actual problem: My problem was to find a rationale, and this question is to find the rationale.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Well, for one thing, one could argue that "not finding a use case" isn't going to cause any problems for you.

Comment: @Mehrdad i will definitely have sleepless nights.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: lol, that's why I haven't close-voted this myself. :P I'm not sure how well that reason would fly for other users on SO but I guess in your case it would work lol.

Comment: Seriously, I don't think that's a good point (and I doubt that this is the intent of the FAQ). Only allow questions if the questioner gets into problems if he doesn't get an answer? Many valid SO questions would need to be closed. For one example, we explicitly encourage people to ask and self-answer questions the answer to which they already know.

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, this is a great question for Stack Overflow. Curiosity is a completely valid "actual problem"; we are all on this sphere to further our knowledge, whether our bosses asked us to or not. Getting fired as an alternative is not a pre-requisite for questions - in fact, usually _those_ questions suck horribly.

Comment: (I think the FAQ wording "actual problems that you face" is unfortunate in this instance, despite its good intentions in mandating _concrete_ problems, which is subtly different.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, but at the same time idle curiosity has been discouraged on SO [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127799/154726) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132320/154726) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113789/154726) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/downvoting-because-of-not-being-practical#comment375021_134714) and elsewhere, many times over.

Comment: @Mehrdad: By that one person. And it looks like he just took that from the literal FAQ wording, too. The FAQ is written for clarity to newbies and lacks nuance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, by quite a lot of people, including mods; see my edit to the comments.

Comment: The second and third links are completely different. The second is about other things, and the third is about "interest" questions that did not talk about _concrete_ things. That is the nuance. Stack Overflow does not and will never require you to prove that you will take a solution to a _concrete_ question and use it to save your job and children's scholarships, no matter what you read from the naysayers on Meta. And we are now wildly off-topic.

Comment: FWIW, I'm a C++ programmer and knowing why certain constructs are part of C++ increases my likelyhood to stay in charge longer than not knowing. This sounds like a real life *actual problem* for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems this is allowed to avoid the need to special case template using a pointer type and a value for `std::nullptr_t`. That, the use case would look look something like this:

```
template <typename T, T Ptr>
struct pointer_object {
    static T get_pointer() { return Ptr; }
};

int int_ptr(0);

typedef pointer_object<int*, &int_ptr> int_ptr_t;
typedef pointer_object<std::nullptr_t, nullptr> null_ptr_t;
```

That is, pointer values can be template arguments and, thus, `nullptr` should be, too.

Answer (score 9):

I guess it's most useful in a setting like this:

```
template <typename T, T Value> struct Foo;

Foo<int, 10> x;
Foo<std::nullptr_t, nullptr> y;
```

No harm in that.

(Maybe `std::integral_constant` is an example of this.)

Comment: @Öö, Proper use cases are good rationales IMHO. But I don't quite see the use of this :) Why isn't `Foo<void, (void())> y;` allowed aswell?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: `void` is an incomplete type that can never be completed.

Comment: I don't understand that rationale. `void()` is a valid expression, and just like for `nullptr_t` which also only has a single value ("null pointer constant"), it could serve as a valid template argument for a `void` template parameter. So why not allow it and let the rationale be that then you could use it with the above `Foo` template?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: But non-type template parameters must have *values*, not just be expressions, non? `(void())` doesn't have a value... that's just my gut feeling.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Could you keep your speculation to yourself please? I've certainly not downvoted this answer and I've actually *upvoted* Johannes's question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I was joking. We're all friends here