# What are the advantages of using nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, null, c++-faq, nullptr

This piece of code *conceptually* does the same thing for the three pointers (safe pointer initialization):

```
int* p1 = nullptr;
int* p2 = NULL;
int* p3 = 0;
```

And so, what are the advantages of assigning pointers `nullptr` over assigning them the values `NULL` or `0`?

Comment: For one thing, an overloaded function taking `int` and `void *` won't choose the `int` version over the `void *` version when using `nullptr`.

Comment: Well `f(nullptr)` is different from `f(NULL)`. But as far as the above code is concerned(assigning to a local variable), all the three pointers are exactly the same. The only advantage is code readability.

Comment: I am in favor of making this an FAQ, @Prasoon. Thanks!

Comment: NB NULL is historically not guaranteed to be 0, but is as oc C99, in the much the same way a byte wasn't necessarily 8 bits long and true and false were architecture dependant values. This question focuses on `nullptr` butthat's the difference between 0 and `NULL`

Answer (score 193, accepted):

In that code, there doesn't seem to be an advantage. But consider the following overloaded functions:

```
void f(char const *ptr);
void f(int v);

f(NULL);  //which function will be called?
```

Which function will be called? Of course, the intention here is to call `f(char const *)`, but in reality `f(int)` will be called! That is a big problem<sup>1</sup>, isn't it?

So, the solution to such problems is to use `nullptr`:

```
f(nullptr); //first function is called
```

---

Of course, that is not the only advantage of `nullptr`.  Here is another:

```
template<typename T, T *ptr>
struct something{};                     //primary template

template<>
struct something<nullptr_t, nullptr>{};  //partial specialization for nullptr
```

Since in template, the type of `nullptr` is deduced as `nullptr_t`, so you can write this:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T *ptr);   //function to handle non-nullptr argument

void f(nullptr_t); //an overload to handle nullptr argument!!!
```

---

<sup>1. In C++, `NULL` is defined as `#define NULL 0`, so it is basically `int`, that is why `f(int)` is called.</sup>

Comment: As what Mehrdad had stated, these kinds of overloads are pretty rare. Are there other relevant advantages of `nullptr`? (No. I'm not demanding)

Comment: Well, I honestly don't know what `something` is for ;). Nice.

Comment: Wait. Why would I want to have `something<nullptr_t, nullptr> sumThing`?

Comment: @MarkGarcia, This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665349/what-is-a-proper-use-case-of-stdnullptr-t-template-parameters

Comment: @MarkGarcia: One might need `something<nullptr_t, nullptr>` especially in template metaprogramming.

Comment: Your footnote seems backwards. `NULL` is required by the standard to have an integral type, and that's why it's typically defined as `0` or `0L`. Also I'm not sure I like that `nullptr_t` overload, since it catches *only* calls with `nullptr`, not with a null pointer of a different type, like `(void*)0`. But I can believe it has some uses, even if all it does is save you defining a single-valued place-holder type of your own to mean "none".

Comment: Another advantage (though admittedly minor) may be that `nullptr` has a well-defined numeric value whereas null pointer constants do not. A null pointer constant is converted to the null pointer of that type (whatever that is). It is required that two null pointers of the same type compare identically, and boolean conversion turns a null pointer into `false`. _Nothing else is required._ Therefore, it is possible for a compiler (silly, but possible) to use e.g. `0xabcdef1234` or some other number for the null pointer. On the other hand, `nullptr` is required to convert to numeric zero.

Comment: On a second thought, "silly" is not so silly at all. A compiler could use distinct null pointer values for every type (in an address range that will certainly segfault), so a crash handler or debugger could immediately tell the type of a dereferenced null pointer only by looking at the raw address. This would not only be "not silly", but actually quite cool.

Comment: @Damon: Are you implying that `NULL` could have a value other than `0`?

Comment: This is incorrect. The real motivation was the need for forwarding. This trivial case can be solved by a cast.

Comment: @DeadMG: What is incorrect in my answer? that `f(nullptr)` will not call the intended function? There were more than one motivations. Many other useful things can be discovered by the programmers themselves in the coming years. So you cannot say that there is *only one true usage* of `nullptr`.

Comment: @DeadMG: Also, the downvoting is silly *even if* my answer doesn't talk about the _real_ motivation. It is like downvoting an answer which talks about C++ template metaprogramming, giving a silly reason that "template was NOT added to do metaprogramming" (yes, it was DISCOVORED).

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, of course. The standard says that null literals are equivalent to a numeric value of zero (the literals, not the assigned pointers!), and they convert to the null pointer of the respective type. There are additional constraints (see above) but it does not say that the null pointer of a type must have any particular numeric value. In fact, by stating that nullpointers _of equal type_ compare equal, it is explicitly _not_ guaranteed that two null pointers of _different_ types compare equal. So, if `int* a=0; char* b=0; assert(a == b);` fails, that't totally allowable.

Comment: Ok, it's not allowable to compare the pointers like this... but you get the idea. If you cast them to integers so it compiles, the assert may fail.

Comment: @Damon: No, `NULL` cannot be any value other than `0`. It must be zero. Who said *"it's not allowable to compare the pointers like this"*? You can compare pointers.

Comment: @Nawaz: Comparing distinct pointer types the way I did above isn't allowed (not without cast, anyway), therefore that won't compile, but that's irrelevant for what I was saying (adding a cast to `intptr_t` wouldn't have fit into a comment anyway). About `NULL` and `nullptr`, note that they're different things. `NULL` is a macro for `0`, an integer literal which is implicitly converted to a null pointer (not `nullptr`) value. And this certainly **can** be something other than zero. It is not specified what value a null pointer of some type has, so if it's zero, that's just convenience or luck.

Comment: The footnote needs correction. In C++ `NULL` has an implementation defined value, with possible definitions which can either `0` or `0L`.

Comment: Is this really supposed to be `template<typename T, T *ptr> struct something {};`, or rather `template<typename T, T ptr> ...` (without the `*`)?

Comment: @Taral: Both will work. `nullptr` can initialize both `nullptr_t` and `nullptr_t*`!!! Why I used `T*`, because I wanted to demonstrate the pointer semantic. See [this](http://ideone.com/XRjtXk) ... and [this](http://ideone.com/zC41dq). I appreciate your comment BTW. :-)

Comment: @AlokSave: You mean the given example definitions for `NULL` are `0` and `0L`. It just needs to be a null-pointer constant implicitly convertible to any pointer type. `nullptr` fits the bill.

Answer (score 92):

C++11 introduces `nullptr`, it is known as the `Null` pointer constant and It ***improves type safety*** and ***resolves ambiguous situations*** unlike the existing implementation dependent null pointer constant `NULL`. To be able to understand the advantages of `nullptr`. we first need to understand what is `NULL` and what are the problems associated with it.

---

### What is `NULL` exactly?

Pre C++11 `NULL` was used to represent a pointer that has no value or pointer that does not point to anything valid. Contrary to the popular notion **`NULL` is not a keyword in C++**. It is an identifier defined in standard library headers. In short you cannot use `NULL` without including some standard library headers. Consider the **[Sample program](http://ideone.com/ASjTaL)**:

```
int main()
{ 
    int *ptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:3:16: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope
```

The C++ standard defines NULL as an implementation defined macro defined in certain standard library header files.
The origin of NULL is from C and C++ inherited it from C. The C standard defined NULL as `0` or `(void *)0`. But in C++ there is a subtle difference.

C++ could not accept this specification as it is. Unlike C, C++ is a strongly typed language (C does not require explicit cast from `void*` to any type, while C++ mandates a explicit cast). This makes the definition of NULL specified by C standard useless in many C++ expressions. For example:

```
std::string * str = NULL;         //Case 1
void (A::*ptrFunc) () = &A::doSomething;
if (ptrFunc == NULL) {}           //Case 2
```

If NULL was defined as `(void *)0`, neither of above expressions would work.

- **Case 1:** Will not compile because a automatic cast is needed from `void *` to `std::string`.
- **Case 2:** Will not compile because cast from `void *` to pointer to member function is needed.

So unlike C, C++ Standard mandated to define NULL as numeric literal `0` or `0L`.

---

### So what is the need for another null pointer constant when we have `NULL` already?

Though the C++ Standards committee came up with a NULL definition which will work for C++, this definition had its own fair share of problems. NULL worked well enough for almost all scenarios but not all. It gave surprising and erroneous results for certain rare scenarios. **[For example](http://ideone.com/EOq9f0)**:

```
#include<iostream>
void doSomething(int)
{
    std::cout<<"In Int version";
}
void doSomething(char *)
{
   std::cout<<"In char* version";
}

int main()
{
    doSomething(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
In Int version
```

Clearly, the intention seems to be to call the version which takes `char*` as the argument, but as the output shows the function which takes an `int` version gets called. This is because NULL is a numeric literal.

Furthermore, since it is implementation-defined whether NULL is 0 or 0L, there can lot of confusion in function overload resolution.

**Sample Program:**

```
#include <cstddef>

void doSomething(int);
void doSomething(char *);

int main()
{
  doSomething(static_cast <char *>(0));    // Case 1
  doSomething(0);                          // Case 2
  doSomething(NULL)                        // Case 3
}
```

Analyzing the above snippet:

- **Case 1:** calls `doSomething(char *)` as expected.
- **Case 2:** calls `doSomething(int)` but maybe `char*` version was be desired because `0` IS also a null pointer.
- **Case 3:** If `NULL` is defined as `0`, calls `doSomething(int)` when perhaps `doSomething(char *)` was intended, perhaps resulting in logic error at runtime.   If `NULL` is defined as `0L`, the call is ambiguous and results in compilation error.

So, depending on implementation, the same code can give various outcomes, which is clearly undesired. Naturally, the C++ standards committee wanted to correct this and that is the prime motivation for nullptr.

---

### So what is `nullptr` and how does it avoid the problems of `NULL`?

C++11 introduces a new keyword `nullptr` to serve as null pointer constant. Unlike NULL, its behavior is not implementation-defined. It is not a macro but it has its own type. nullptr has the type `std::nullptr_t`. C++11 appropriately defines properties for the nullptr to avoid the disadvantages of NULL. To summarize its properties:

**Property 1:** it has its own type `std::nullptr_t`, and
**Property 2:** it is implicitly convertible and comparable to any pointer type or pointer-to-member type, but
**Property 3:** it is not implicitly convertible or comparable to integral types, except for `bool`.

Consider the following example:

```
#include<iostream>
void doSomething(int)
{
    std::cout<<"In Int version";
}
void doSomething(char *)
{
   std::cout<<"In char* version";
}

int main()
{
    char *pc = nullptr;      // Case 1
    int i = nullptr;         // Case 2
    bool flag = nullptr;     // Case 3

    doSomething(nullptr);    // Case 4
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program,

- **Case 1:** OK - Property 2
- **Case 2:** Not Ok - Property 3
- **Case 3:** OK - Property 3
- **Case 4:** No confusion - Calls `char *` version, Property 2 & 3

Thus introduction of nullptr avoids all the problems of good old NULL.

### How and where should you use `nullptr`?

The rule of thumb for C++11 is simply start using `nullptr` whenever you would have otherwise used NULL in the past.

---

<sup>**Standard References:**</sup>

<sup>C++11 Standard: C.3.2.4 Macro NULL</sup>
<sup>C++11 Standard: 18.2 Types</sup>
<sup>C++11 Standard: 4.10 Pointer conversions</sup>
<sup>C99 Standard: 6.3.2.3 Pointers</sup>

Comment: I'm already practicing your last advice since I've known `nullptr`, though I did not know what difference it really does to my code. Thanks for the great answer and especially for the effort. Brought me a great deal light on the topic.

Comment: "in certain standard library header files." -> why not just write "cstddef" from the beginning?

Comment: Why should we allow nullptr to be convertible to bool type? Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: *...was used to represent a pointer that has no value...* Variables **always** has a value. It may be noise, or `0xccccc....`, but, a value-less variable is an inherent contradiction.

Comment: "Case 3: OK - Property 3" (line `bool flag = nullptr;`). Nope, not OK, I get the following error at compile time with g++ 6: `error: converting to ‘bool’ from ‘std::nullptr_t’ requires direct-initialization [-fpermissive]`

Answer (score 24):

The real motivation here is *perfect forwarding*.

Consider:

```
void f(int* p);
template<typename T> void forward(T&& t) {
    f(std::forward<T>(t));
}
int main() {
    forward(0); // FAIL
}
```

Simply put, 0 is a special *value*, but values cannot propagate through the system- only types can. Forwarding functions are essential, and 0 can't deal with them. Thus, it was absolutely necessary to introduce `nullptr`, where the *type* is what is special, and the type can indeed propagate. In fact, the MSVC team had to introduce `nullptr` ahead of schedule after they implemented rvalue references and then discovered this pitfall for themselves.

There are a few other corner cases where `nullptr` can make life easier- but it's not a core case, as a cast can solve these problems. Consider

```
void f(int);
void f(int*);
int main() { f(0); f(nullptr); }
```

Calls two separate overloads. In addition, consider

```
void f(int*);
void f(long*);
int main() { f(0); }
```

This is ambiguous. But, with nullptr, you can provide

```
void f(std::nullptr_t)
int main() { f(nullptr); }
```

Comment: Funny. The half of the answer is same as other two answers which according to you is *"quite incorrect"* answers!!!

Comment: The forwarding problem can also be solved with a cast. `forward((int*)0)` works. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

**Basics of nullptr**

`std::nullptr_t` is the type of the null pointer literal, nullptr. It is a prvalue/rvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. There exist implicit conversions from nullptr to null pointer value of any pointer type.

The literal 0 is an int, not a pointer. If C++ finds itself looking at 0 in a context where only a pointer can be used, it’ll grudgingly interpret 0 as a null pointer, but that’s a fallback position. C++’s primary policy is that 0 is an int, not a pointer.

**Advantage 1 - Remove ambiguity when overloading on pointer and integral types**

In C++98, the primary implication of this was that overloading on pointer and integral types could lead to surprises. Passing 0 or NULL to such overloads never called a pointer overload:

```
   void fun(int); // two overloads of fun
    void fun(void*);
    fun(0); // calls f(int), not fun(void*)
    fun(NULL); // might not compile, but typically calls fun(int). Never calls fun(void*)
```

The interesting thing about that call is the contradiction between the apparent meaning of the source code (“I am calling fun with NULL-the null pointer”) and its actual meaning (“I am calling fun with some kind of integer— not the null pointer”).

nullptr’s advantage is that it doesn’t have an integral type.
Calling the overloaded function fun with nullptr calls the void* overload (i.e., the pointer overload), because nullptr can’t be viewed as anything integral:

```
fun(nullptr); // calls fun(void*) overload
```

Using nullptr instead of 0 or NULL thus avoids overload resolution surprises.

**Another advantage of `nullptr` over `NULL(0)` when using auto for return type**

For example, suppose you encounter this in a code base:

```
auto result = findRecord( /* arguments */ );
if (result == 0) {
....
}
```

If you don’t happen to know (or can’t easily find out) what findRecord returns, it may not be clear whether result is a pointer type or an integral type. After all, 0 (what result is tested against) could go either way. If you see the following, on the other hand,

```
auto result = findRecord( /* arguments */ );
if (result == nullptr) {
...
}
```

there’s no ambiguity: result must be a pointer type.

**Advantage 3**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
int f1(std::shared_ptr<int> spw) // call these only when
{
  //do something
  return 0;
}
double f2(std::unique_ptr<int> upw) // the appropriate
{
  //do something
  return 0.0;
}
bool f3(int* pw) // mutex is locked
{

return 0;
}

std::mutex f1m, f2m, f3m; // mutexes for f1, f2, and f3
using MuxtexGuard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;

void lockAndCallF1()
{
        MuxtexGuard g(f1m); // lock mutex for f1
        auto result = f1(static_cast<int>(0)); // pass 0 as null ptr to f1
        cout<< result<<endl;
}

void lockAndCallF2()
{
        MuxtexGuard g(f2m); // lock mutex for f2
        auto result = f2(static_cast<int>(NULL)); // pass NULL as null ptr to f2
        cout<< result<<endl;
}
void lockAndCallF3()
{
        MuxtexGuard g(f3m); // lock mutex for f2
        auto result = f3(nullptr);// pass nullptr as null ptr to f3 
        cout<< result<<endl;
} // unlock mutex
int main()
{
        lockAndCallF1();
        lockAndCallF2();
        lockAndCallF3();
        return 0;
}
```

Above program compile and executed successfully but lockAndCallF1, lockAndCallF2 & lockAndCallF3 have redundant code. It is pity to write code like this if we can write template for all these `lockAndCallF1, lockAndCallF2 & lockAndCallF3`. So it can be generalized with template. I have written template function `lockAndCall` instead of multiple definition `lockAndCallF1, lockAndCallF2 & lockAndCallF3` for redundant code.

Code is re-factored as below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
int f1(std::shared_ptr<int> spw) // call these only when
{
  //do something
  return 0;
}
double f2(std::unique_ptr<int> upw) // the appropriate
{
  //do something
  return 0.0;
}
bool f3(int* pw) // mutex is locked
{

return 0;
}

std::mutex f1m, f2m, f3m; // mutexes for f1, f2, and f3
using MuxtexGuard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;

template<typename FuncType, typename MuxType, typename PtrType>
auto lockAndCall(FuncType func, MuxType& mutex, PtrType ptr) -> decltype(func(ptr))
//decltype(auto) lockAndCall(FuncType func, MuxType& mutex, PtrType ptr)
{
        MuxtexGuard g(mutex);
        return func(ptr);
}
int main()
{
        auto result1 = lockAndCall(f1, f1m, 0); //compilation failed 
        //do something
        auto result2 = lockAndCall(f2, f2m, NULL); //compilation failed
        //do something
        auto result3 = lockAndCall(f3, f3m, nullptr);
        //do something
        return 0;
}
```

**Detail analysis why compilation failed for `lockAndCall(f1, f1m, 0) & lockAndCall(f3, f3m, nullptr)` not for `lockAndCall(f3, f3m, nullptr)`**

**Why compilation of `lockAndCall(f1, f1m, 0) & lockAndCall(f3, f3m, nullptr)` failed?**

The problem is that when 0 is passed to lockAndCall, template type deduction kicks in to figure out its type. The type of 0 is int, so that’s the type of the parameter ptr inside the instantiation of this call to lockAndCall. Unfortunately, this means that in the call to func inside lockAndCall, an int is being passed, and that’s not compatible with the `std::shared_ptr<int>` parameter that `f1` expects. The 0 passed in the call to `lockAndCall` was intended to represent a null pointer, but what actually got passed was int. Trying to pass this int to f1 as a `std::shared_ptr<int>` is a type error. The call to `lockAndCall` with 0 fails because inside the template, an int is being passed to a function that requires a `std::shared_ptr<int>`.

The analysis for the call involving `NULL` is essentially the same. When `NULL` is passed to `lockAndCall`, an integral type is deduced for the parameter ptr, and a type error occurs when `ptr`—an int or int-like type—is passed to `f2`, which expects to get a `std::unique_ptr<int>`.

In contrast, the call involving `nullptr` has no trouble. When `nullptr` is passed to `lockAndCall`, the type for `ptr` is deduced to be `std::nullptr_t`. When `ptr` is passed to `f3`, there’s an implicit conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to `int*`, because `std::nullptr_t` implicitly converts to all pointer types.

**It is recommended, Whenever you want to refer to a null pointer, use nullptr, not 0 or `NULL`.**

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct advantage of having `nullptr` in the way you have shown the examples.
But consider a situation where you have 2 functions with same name; 1 takes `int` and another an `int*`

```
void foo(int);
void foo(int*);
```

If you want to call `foo(int*)` by passing a NULL, then the way is:

```
foo((int*)0); // note: foo(NULL) means foo(0)
```

`nullptr` makes it more **easy and intuitive**:

```
foo(nullptr);
```

[Additional link](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#nullptr) from Bjarne's webpage.
Irrelevant but on C++11 side note:

```
auto p = 0; // makes auto as int
auto p = nullptr; // makes auto as decltype(nullptr)
```

Comment: For reference, `decltype(nullptr)` is `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: @chris Is `std::nullptr_t` a typedef, #define or something?

Comment: @MarkGarcia, It's a full-blown type as far as I know.

Comment: @chris And so, is it a (real) pointer type? And if it is, what type does it point to? (I'm really curious. Seriously.)

Comment: @MarkGarcia, It's an interesting question. cppreference has: `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;`. I guess I can look in the standard. Ah, found it: *Note: std::nullptr_t
is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value.*

Comment: @chris Oh. They really like to always take things differently then. Still, thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: It's a really good thing you pointed out the deduction of `nullptr`.

Comment: This is quite incorrect. Perfect forwarding was the true motivation.

Comment: @DeadMG: There were more than one motivations. Many other useful things can be discovered by the programmers themselves in the coming years. So you cannot say that there is *only one true usage* of `nullptr`.

Comment: I never said there was one true usage. I said there was one motivation, namely, that 0 cannot forward for shit and `nullptr` can.

Comment: @DeadMG: But you said this answer is *"quite incorrect"* simply because it doesn't talk about *"the true motivation"* you talked about in your answer. Not only that this answer (and mine as well) received a downvote from you.

Comment: Well, since forwarding is the primary motivation, then any answer not discussing it is quite incorrect.

Comment: @DeadMG: That is superlatively dumb. An answer is wrong when it gives you wrong information. But this answer (as well as mine) doesn't give any wrong information.

Comment: It suggests that the motivation for nullptr was something other than perfect forwarding, which it was not.

Comment: @DeadMG: The motivation was obviously NOT one; there were many. (Wait, let me guess : now you're going to say "primary" motivation, right?)

Answer (score 4):

Just as others have already said, its primary advantage lies in overloads. And while explicit `int` vs. pointer overloads can be rare, consider standard library functions like `std::fill` (which has bitten me more than once in C++03):

```
MyClass *arr[4];
std::fill_n(arr, 4, NULL);
```

Doesn't compile: `Cannot convert int to MyClass*`.

Answer (score 2):

IMO more important than those overload issues: in deeply nested template constructs, it's hard not to lose track of the types, and giving explicit signatures is quite an endeavour. So for everything that you use, the more precisely focused to the intended purpose, the better, it will reduce the need for explicit signatures and allows the compiler to produce more insightful error messages when something goes wrong.