# C++: Empty if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is more of an entry level question, but I'm wondering if it's good practice to have an empty if statement.

Consider this code:

```
void RabbitList::purge()
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        //cout << "Can't purge an empty colony!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Kill half the colony
        for(int amountToKill = (getColonySize()) / 2; amountToKill != 0;)
        {
            RabbitNode * curr = head;
            RabbitNode * trail = NULL;

            bool fiftyFiftyChance = randomGeneration(2);

            //If the random check succeeded but we're still on the head node
            if(fiftyFiftyChance == 1 && curr == head)
            {
                head = curr->next;
                delete curr;
                --size;
                --amountToKill;
            }
            //If the random check succeeded and we're beyond the head, but not on last node
            else if(fiftyFiftyChance == 1 && curr->next != NULL)
            {
                trail->next = curr->next;
                delete curr;
                --size;
                --amountToKill;
            }
            //If the random check succeeded, but we're on the last node
            else if(fiftyFiftyChance == 1)
            {
                trail->next = NULL;
                delete curr;
                --size;
                --amountToKill;
            }
            //If the random check failed
            else
            {
                trail = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
        cout << "Food shortage! Colony has been purged by half." << endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the if statement on line 5 is currently commented out; this was more of a debug text and I don't want to send any feedback to the console anymore. I'm pretty sure it would be considered bad practice to have the if statement do nothing. I know I could have return;

but since my return type is void it gives me an error. What if my return type is not void for example?

Comment: This a style question, so inherently subjective.  But a good rule of thumb is to never have commented-out code lying around in your codebase.

Comment: @Oli Thanks for your answer. I'm learning this by my own, so since I have no direct mentoring I still prefer to ask these kind of questions.

Comment: Just a side note: using the macro `NULL` is now deprecated, prefer `nullptr`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385

Comment: One may even put the "head" condition on the for loop

Comment: I was tempted to post an empty answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of the `if` part, up to the first `else`, and replace it with `if (head)`, which is the opposite condition, thus perfect for replacing the `else` in an if-else situation. However, there is then the matter of an extra tab of indentation for the entire function. At that point, it does become more preference, but I myself prefer to get the check out of the way early and not have the indentation.

If you need to return from anywhere, you can do so with `return;`.

Comment: So:
    if(head != NULL) AND    if(head)
are the one and same thing, correct?

As is if(head == NULL) AND if(!head)?

Comment: @Marcan, Yes, I much prefer the shorter forms.

Comment: Thank you. What about in a longer statement thats checks 2 conditions? For example: if(mutantCount() > 0 && head). Or is it better to write: if(mutantCount() > 0 && head != NULL) for clarity?

Comment: @Marcan, `head` should be just as clear, especially with pointers.

Answer (score 6):

Even if your return type is void it is legal to `return` there, and certainly since the `if` has braces, atleast this isnt a bug waiting to happen. However it is not pretty and involves a little more work to read/understand.

You could **reword** it to

```
if(head == NULL) // or if(!head)
    return;

....
```

This should remove the need for the else, and the rest of the code is now inside the function and not a nested scope, a happy perk.

Comment: This is my preference.  When you have a simple function and some conditions will cause it to do nothing, then I like to detect those at the start and return.  That way I avoid excessive indentation and have a policy that if I reach the end of the function, then it was successful.

Answer (score 5):

For a single branch, just write it directly:

```
if (head != 0) {
    // whatever
}
```

For multiple branches, sometimes having an empty first branch can simplify the conditions that follow:

```
if (head == 0) {
    // nothing to do
} else if (head->next == 0) {
    // whatever
} else {
    // whatever else
}
```

Yes, you could write that last one with an additional layer:

```
if (head != 0) {
    if (head->next == 0) {
        // whatever
    } else {
        // whatever else
    }
}
```

but the first form is clearer, especially when the second form would end up with three or four levels of if.

Oh, and

```
if (head == 0)
    return;
```

can sometimes be difficult, since it introduces an extra point of exit to the function. In the past I was a fan of this form, but in the past few years I've found that I end up removing it pretty consistently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually believe this is subjective.  Why write dead code?  It is a tell-tale sign of a beginner. Instead, just check for the condition you are after and be done with it:

```
if(!head)
   // stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote your function by removing repetition and redundancy.  It boils down reasonably small.

```
void RabbitList::purge()
{
    if(head == NULL) return;

    //Kill half the colony
    for(int amountToKill = (getColonySize()) / 2; amountToKill != 0;)
    {
        RabbitNode * curr = head;
        RabbitNode * trail = NULL;

        bool fiftyFiftyChance = randomGeneration(2);

        if(fiftyFiftyChance == 1 )
        {
            if( curr == head)
                head = curr->next;
            else
                trail->next = curr->next;

            delete curr;
            --size;
            --amountToKill;
        }
        else
        {
            trail = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    cout << "Food shortage! Colony has been purged by half." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great. Just going through your code made me realize how I could optimize it and therefore, make it more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Oli stated in a comment, this is a subjective style issue. You have two choices:

```
if (<something is true>) {
    // Do nothing
} else {
    // Some code goes here
}
```

or

```
if (!<something is true>) {
    // Code goes here
}
```

I can imagine situations where the former can be more readable than the second, especially if the condition is moderately complex.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it.

But I would virtualize the logging (std::cout is not always useful).

```
struct NullLogger : public Logger
{
    virtual void log(std::string const&) {}
};

// By default use the Null Logger
// But if you need to debug just pass a useful specialization of logging.
void RabbitList::purge(Logger const& logger = NullLogger())
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        logger.log("Can't purge an empty colony!");
    }
    else
    {
```

Comment: @Lieuwe: Complete ballder-dash.