# Where / How is null defined?

Tags: c++, null

Null is not declared?

My code:

```
// Include necessary libraries
#include <cstdlib> // Exits
#include <iostream> // I/O
#include <cstring> // String functions
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Declare local Constants and Variables
    const char SOKINP[19] = "23456789TtJjQqKkAa"; // Valid Input Characters
    char acCards [5]; // Array to hold up to five cards (user input)
    bool bErr;        // Loop on Error (Calculated)
    int  i,           // Loop variable (Calculated)
    iNbrCrd,          // Number of Cards 2-5 (user input)
    iNAces,           // Number of Aces (Calculated)
    iTS;              // Total Score (Calculated)

    ...

    for (i=0;i<iNbrCrd;i++){
       do {
           cout << "Enter Card #" << i << " (2-9,t,j,q,k or a)  >";
           cin  >> acCards[i];
           cout << endl;
           bErr = (strchr(SOKINP, acCards[i]) == null) ? true : false; // *ERROR*
       } while (bErr);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Error] 'null' was not declared in this scope

How do I declare 'null'?  I tried including several other libraries.
I'm using Dev C++ v5.4.2

Thanks, ~d

Comment: Use `NULL` or `nullptr`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: You should say : Use `nullptr` (or `NULL`). The order emphasizes and the emphasise matters.

Comment: @Nawaz He's using Dev C++. Unless it's been updated, `nullptr` is not going to work for him.

Comment: @ta.speot.is In this case, you should say: "don't use Dev-C++ but a good C++ compiler, and use `nullptr`".

Comment: 0 works just fine and should work for all compilers.

Comment: @CareyGregory: yes that should work for all compilers, though **not** in all situations which is why `nullptr` was added to the language.

Comment: @Nawaz - In what situation does `0` not work?

Comment: @CareyGregory: [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr) gives lots of such example. See every answer.

Comment: @Nawaz - Meanwhile, before I've even had a chance to read your link, a C solution to the problem has garnered 5 upvotes and been accepted.  So I'll go read the link now and maybe learn something instead of hanging around this thread.  :-)

Comment: @Nawaz +1.  The overloading example is compelling.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Perhaps it's from being a noob, but I think Dev-C++ is a good compiler (at least from an 'ease of use' standpoint.)   What compiler do you recommend (for Win 7 Ult, x64)?

Comment: I had some char to short conversion error I couldn't resolve (later in my code) and ended up using the .find method with size_t type and string::npos as equality verifier.

Comment: @DaveC On Windows, either use 1. Microsoft's Visual Studio IDE that includes their own compiler, or 2. the Code::Blocks IDE and/or the MinGW environment, which both come with GCC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not `null`. It's `NULL` in all caps. If writing `NULL` does not work, you can define it yourself by using

```
#define NULL 0
```

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart You will get type mismatch warnings **exactly** when you define it as `(void *)0`. In C and C++, `0` is a valid literal for null pointers of **any type**, but `(void *)0` only works with pointers to `void`, due to strict strong typing in C++. Thus, `(void *)0` is safer in C than `0`, but it's **wrong** in C++.

Comment: Noob mistake. Doh!  Thank you everyone, capitalizing it was the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NULL` instead of Null.

If you are using it to initialize a pointer and you are using C++11, use `nullptr`.

Although `NULL` works for assigning the pointers(even though `NULL` is not a pointer type but is integer), you may face problems in the below case:

```
void func(int n);
void func(char *s);

func( NULL ); // guess which function gets called?
```

Refer to [THIS](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) for more details