# why this segmentation fault (core dumped) ??? int main (int argc, char *argv[])

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault, argc

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a, b, quo, rest;

    void division(int dividendo, int divisor, int *ptr_quociente, int *ptr_resto)
    {
        *ptr_quociente=dividendo/divisor;
        *ptr_resto=dividendo%divisor;
    }

    if(argc=3)
    {
        a= atoi(argv[1]);   
        b= atoi(argv[2]);    

        division(a,b,&quo,&rest);

        printf(" %d and %d \n",quo,rest);
    }
    else if (argc=1)
        do
        {
            printf("type two int numbers:\n");

            scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

            division(a,b,&quo,&rest);

            printf(" %d and %d \n",quo,rest);

        } while(a!=0);
}
```

if I do:

> ./program.c 12 6

it works but if I do:

> ./program.c

I get a segmentation fault, why?

Comment: `argc=3` should be `argc==3`

Comment: thank you! i should have seen it, kind of tired...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(argc=3) should be if(3 == arc) //notice '=='
```

That's why it is always good idea to keep `constant` on `LHS`, this will avoid accidental assignment

Same with `arc=1`

Also, I moved local function definition outside main.

```
void division(int dividendo, int divisor, int *ptr_quociente, int *ptr_resto)

{

       *ptr_quociente=dividendo/divisor;
       *ptr_resto=dividendo%divisor;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{
...
}
```

**Edit:** After reading comments from Paxdiablo and Shafik, I came to know most modern compiler would warn for `'='` in condition. You can simply write `if(argc == 3)` rather than placing constant on `LHS`.

Comment: Bah, that's what I like to call "butt-ugly format", especially since modern compilers can warn about assignments within conditionals. But +1 anyway since you found the problem, even as I laugh derisively at your solution :-)

Comment: Ack no, [Yoda condition we need not use with 
a modern compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106713/what-is-the-difference-between-if-null-pointer-vs-if-pointer-null).

Comment: @paxdiablo Shafik, yes kind of agree, as it is defensive programming than anything else. if(arc == 3) should be fine.