# Conditional statement evaluating wrong

Tags: c++

According to the program below, if `donuts = 1` it will assign `0` to `donuts`, but if I run this it shows that `0` is assigned to `donuts`. Please tell me what I am over looking. Because how I see this code donuts should equal `12`, because donuts should have fallen into the else:

```
#include <iostream> // Header file to enable console I/O
#include <string>   // Header file to enable string
#include <iomanip>  // enables maniplution of io strem
using namespace std;

// Begin main Function Definition
int main()
{
int donuts = 10;
if (donuts = 1)
{
    donuts = 0;
}
else
{
    donuts += 2;
}
cout<< donuts;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
// End of main function
```

Comment: Typo, using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Turn on/up your compiler warnings.

Comment: Do `if (1 == donuts)` so you'll get an error if you make the same mistake again.

Comment: @HotLicks with modern compilers [yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22106732/1708801) should not be required anymore.

Comment: @HotLicks well sometimes it is a matter of using the correct warning flags which everyone really should be e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Werror -pedantic` etc... Getting used to using these flags early on will save you a lot of pain in the long run. Also using more than one compiler can be really useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (donuts = 1)
```

should be:

```
if (donuts == 1)
        //^^^
```

You need to use logical equal `==` or assignment `=`

Comment: i am ashamed at how much i over look that....