# Pros and cons of: (a == 0) vs (0 == a)

Tags: c++, coding-style, standards, notation

What are the pros and cons of the two following notations?

```
if (a == 0) ...
```

and

```
if (0 == a) ...
```

The first one is more readable. What about the second one?

Comment: [More readable the second one is.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2012/07/6a0120a85dcdae970b0176169611b8970c-800wi.png)

Comment: The second one is also known as a Yoda condition see [What is the difference between if (NULL == pointer) vs if (pointer == NULL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22106713/1708801) as I note in my answer there for modern compiler this should not be needed anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really only two things at play here:

First is readability, which is self explanitory.

The second is to prevent possible bugs, in your example, it prevents accidentally doing

```
if (a = 0)
```

Some compilers will warn you that you are using the implicit truthiness of the return value of an assignment, but much of the time this is a typo. If you reverse this

```
if (0 = a)
```

it won't even compile, so it is a forced prevention of the bug