# Where does nullptr_t reside?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, nullptr

A bit of prehistory.

I've been writing a game engine for quite some time. It's divided into several static libraries, like "utils", "rsbin" (resource system), "window", which are then linked into a single executable.

It is a crossplatform engine, being compiled for Windows and for Android.
Under Windows, I compile it with MinGW. Under Android, with CCTools, which is an interface to native gcc.

One of the base classes is `utils::RefObject`, which represents a concept similar to Windows's IUnknown: it provides a reference counter to determine its lifetime and a method for querying a specific interface from base class pointer. There's also `template< typename T > utils::Ref`, designed specifically for this kind of objects. It holds an `std::atomic< utils::RefObject* >` and automatically updates its object's refcount upon construction, assignment and destruction, analogously to `std::shared_ptr`. It also allows to implicitly convert RefObjects of different types through their querying methods. Though, it's inefficient to query an object for its own type, so, `utils::Ref` overloads most of its operators, e. g. there's specific `utils::Ref< T >::Ref( T* ptr )` constructor, which simply increments the passed object's refcount, and general `utils::Ref< T >::Ref( RefObject* ptr )`, which queries its argument for instance of T and throws an exception on failure (don't worry, though, there's of course a method for the soft cast).

But having just these two methods introduces a problem: you cannot explicitly initialize `utils::Ref` with a null pointer, as it is ambiguous; so there's also `utils::Ref< T >::Ref( nullptr_t )` to provide a way to do it.

Now, we are getting to the problem at hand. In the header file, the prototype is spelled exactly as above, without any preceding `std::`. Note that I don't use `using namespace` either. For a long time, this worked.

Now, I'm working on a graphics system. It existed before, but it was rather rudimentary, so I didn't even noticed that <gl.h> actually defines only OpenGL 1.1, while for newer versions you should go through <glext.h>. Now, it became necessary to use the latter. But including it broke the old reference class.

Judging from error messages, MinGW now has problems with that `nullptr_t` in prototypes. I've done a quick search on the Web and found that *often* it's referred to as `std::nullptr_t`. Though, not everywhere.

**Quick sumup: I had `nullptr_t` without either `std::` or `using namespace` compiling fine until I included <glext.h> before the header.**

The site I've been using so far, cplusplus.com/reference, suggests that global `::nullptr_t` [is exactly how it should be](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/nullptr_t/). On the other hand, en.cppreference.com wiki [tells that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) it's actually `std::nullptr_t`.

A quick test program, a helloworld with `void foo( int )` and `void foo( nullptr_t )`, failed to compile and the reason now is explicit `"error: 'nullptr_t' was not declared in this scope"` with suggestion to use `std::nullptr_t` instead.

It won't be hard to add `std::` where needed; but this case left me rather curious.

cplusplus.com was actually lying? => Answered in commets, yes. It's an inaccurate source.

Then, if `nullptr_t` actually resides in `namespace std`, why did `utils::Ref` compile? => With suggestions in comments, ran a couple of test and discovered that <mutex>, included in some other header, when placed before any stddef header, defines global `::nullptr_t`. Certainly not an ideal behavior, but it's not a major bug. Probably should report it to MinGW/GCC developers anyway.

Why inclusion of <glext.h> breaks it? => When any stddef header is included before <mutex>, the type is defined according to the standard, as `std::nullptr_t`. <glext.h> includes <windows.h>, which, in turn, certainly includes the stddef header, among with a whole pack of others which are needed for WinAPI.

Here are the sources, defining the class in question:

- [utils/ref.hpp](http://pastebin.com/8ydpP9Aw)
- [utils/ref.cpp](http://pastebin.com/KwSRyDTk)
- [utils/refobject.hpp](http://pastebin.com/7UELQxqz)
- [utils/refobject.cpp](http://pastebin.com/qu1VTiuu)
- [utils/logger.hpp](http://pastebin.com/sGa23tB2) => This one uses a mutex to avoid line tearing during output.
- [utils/cbase.hpp](http://pastebin.com/40upGeer)

(the latter 2 are included and so may affect too)

As suggested in the comments, I ran g++ -E on a test case which compiled, and found a quite interesting bit in <stddef.h>:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L
#ifndef _GXX_NULLPTR_T
#define _GXX_NULLPTR_T
  typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
#endif
#endif /* C++11.  */
```

Now to find where `_GXX_NULLPTR_T` is defined else... a quick GREP through MinGW's files didn't find anything besides this stddef.h

So, it's still a mystery why and how it's getting disabled. Especially when including just <stddef.h> and nothing else does not define `nullptr_t` anywhere, despite the bit above.

Comment: look at the preprocessed output to see where `::nullptr_t` is introduced.

Comment: FWIW, cplusplus.com is known for being inaccurate.

Comment: It belongs in std, non-zero odds that this source code saw another compiler first that had `using ::std::nullptr_t;` in a header.  Like MSVC++.

Comment: @HansPassant Never used another compiler on Windows for this project.

Comment: @tenfour Oh, that helped! Edited OP.

Comment: @Delfigamer It doesn't look like you actually include `<stddef.h>` anywhere, and are relying on some other header including it on your behalf. That's unreliable and won't always work. If you want something defined in that header, include that header.

Comment: Not to be rude, but is 90% of the question necessary?

Comment: @remyabel It answers to possible questions like "why"... "why"... and "why"... No, you can skip it right to the bold line.

Comment: +1 for spending so much effort to add context to the question. It is always a tough one to decide how much context to provide.

Comment: Stupid question on my behalf: Why is he using nullptr_t and not nullptr directly? Is doing so bad for any reason? In other terms - why would one ever need the type of a nullptr? Would not void* be the type used in those cases?

Comment: @user2225104 As stated in OP, `nullptr_t` is used for overloading functions, accepting different kinds of pointers, as otherwise calling them with null pointer would require its explicit typecasting to one of accepted types. When you have `void foo( int* )` and `void foo( double* )`, call to `foo( 0 )` is ambiguous: the compiler doesn't know which function to call. We can typecast the zero to tell which foo we need: `foo( ( double* )0 )` will be resolved to the latter one. But C++11 gives us a more elegant way to do this, by introducing a special-case `void foo( nullptr_t )`...

Comment: @user2225104 ...and then calling `foo( nullptr )` which will unambiguously resolve to its own function. In `utils::Ref`, described in OP, this syntax is used to explicitly initialize the reference with null pointer and to assign one when we don't longer need an object it was holding and giving a new one does not make sense.

Comment: @user2225104 [Also, there's this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr/13816448) ;)

Comment: I start to understand what is going on. Basically, I wonder why they keep splitting functionality between language and std libraries. If nullptr is an intrinsic "value", so should be std::nullptr_t be nullptr_t and language defined (no headers). Same mess they produced with lambda functions and std::function. Just imagine if true and false were language values and bool would not exist. Anyone would see how sick that would be.

Comment: @user2225104 I had this thought about `nullptr_t` too, as I don't see how it is different to `bool` enough so that `bool`, `false` and `true` are all intrinsics, while the type of intrinsic `nullptr` is some declaration in a C header file. It would be more logical to either introduce a written class `std::nullptr_t` with `nullptr_t const nullptr` (which is totally possible in C++) or make them both keywords. Regarding closures and, similarly, initialization lists, they are concepts complex enough to be irrepresentable with elementary types, so there's not many other ways to implement them.

Comment: @delf `bool` is a reserved word in C++.  Adding new reserved words risks breaking backwards compatibility.  So, barring great reasons, it is not done.

Comment: @user2225104 `std::function` has very little to do with lambdas. A `std::function` is a generic functor which can contain anything callable, and has to use type erasure to achieve that (with associated runtime cost). The type of a lambda expression is a unique unnamed class, the "closure type."

Comment: @Angew Try to get happy with lambdas without using std::function. Good luck with that. And that alone is proof that they did splitting and unfortunate splitting of functionality. Had they not been so clumsy regarding type of lambdas, you could actually use them without std::function.

Comment: @user2225104 I use lambdas *a lot,* and I have yet to use them with `std::function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `nullptr` is defined in namespace `::std`, so the correct qualification is `::std::nullptr_t`. Of course, this means you normally spell it `std::nullptr_t` in practice.

Quoting C++11:

2.14.7/1:

> The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

18.2/9:

> `nullptr_t` is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>   typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
> }
> ```
>
> The type for which `nullptr_t` is a synonym has the characteristics described in 3.9.1 and 4.10. [ *Note:*
>   Although `nullptr`’s address cannot be taken, the address of another `nullptr_t` object that is an lvalue can
>   be taken. *—end note* ]

`<stddef.h>` also enters into the picture. 18.2 talks about `<cstddef>`, so that's the C++ header where `std::nullptr_t` is defined. Per D.5/2:

> Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard
>   library namespace by the corresponding `cname` header is placed within the global namespace scope.

Which means that including `<stddef.h>` gives you access to `::nullptr_t`. But since that's supposed to be a C header, I would advise against relying on this in C++ code (even if it's formally valid).

Comment: IMO it doesn't make much sense to say "`nullptr` is of type `nullptr_t`", rather than "`nullptr_t` designates the type of `nullptr`". nullptr_t is merely a typedef.

Comment: Given that the OP's now mentioned `<stddef.h>`, it's probably worth mentioning that that header defines `::nullptr_t` exactly the same way `<cstddef>` defines `::std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: @Columbo I believe there's a DR about that, that the definition in the standard is circular.

Comment: @Columbo Why, the fact is `nullptr` directs to `nullptr_t` argument in overloaded functions, and it doesn't seem there's any conversion here. There are lots of typedefs in C code, but that doesn't stop us to say that, for example, "42 is of type `WORD` while -19 and 0x12345 aren't". Besides, I view both your sentences as denoting the same fact with different words: when calling `foo( nullptr )`, the very first candidate is `void foo( std::nullptr_t )`, like for `foo( 12 )` it's `void foo( int )`.

Comment: @Delfigamer ... I think you missed the point. Obviously both are correct and denote the same thing, but they make differnet implications.

Comment: @hvd Oh, great. When I include <cstddef>, the compiler requires std::nullptr_t. When I include <stddef.h>, there's no type anywhere. Including <cstdio> defined std::nullptr_t. <stdio.h> defines neither.

Comment: @Delfigamer `<stddef.h>` exists for stuff ported from C. Relying on a purely C++ construct such as `nullptr_t` being declared in global scope by `<stddef.h>` is asking for trouble, IMO. It would surprise me if any standard library implementors check conformance in this particular aspect.

Comment: @Angew @hvd Oh, I found! Including <mutex> makes `void foo( nullptr_t )` compile fine. Strange. Very strange. And adding any of <cstddef> and <stddef.h> before <mutex> forces the type into namespace std. I almost see where this is going.