# How is nullptr defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

In *Effective Modern C++*, "Iterm 8: Prefer nullptr to 0 and NULL.", Page 59, it says:

> `nullptr`'s actual type is `std::nullptr_t`, and, in a wonderfully circular definition, `std::nullptr_t` is defined to be the type of `nullptr`.

A wonderfully circular definition?

How that comes?

Comment: It's a trick in the compiler itself

Comment: Actural?  Is that a misquote?

Comment: You can find some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)

Comment: And also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696522/where-does-nullptr-t-reside).

Comment: The quote is misleading. Although the type of `nullptr` is `std::nullptr_t`, the standard does not use it to define `nullptr`. So there is no circular definition. The behavior of `nullptr` and  `std::nullptr_t` are defined by various statements scattered in the standard.

Comment: Joke of the day:  `auto p = new decltype(nullptr);` .   Do not do this in actual code.

Comment: @Eljay: That would make a non-null `std::nullptr_t *`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You have that backwards, I think. The definition of `nullptr` is literally nothing more than "The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`." and its useful properties are given to all `nullptr_t` values regardless of whether they come from a `nullptr` literal. But the standard does not rely on `nullptr` in the definition of `nullptr_t` aside from mentioning again, redundantly, that it is the type of that, so there is indeed no circular definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, `nullptr` is a value that can be assigned to a pointer to any type, and it is false in boolean context (unlike most pointers that are results of `new`/`malloc`, or referencing a valid object), and despite itself being a valid pointer, dereferencing it results in UB, as does in/decrementing it, and it is a sole value of a singleton type `nullptr_t`.

Something like this.

Comment: that reads like a random pointer not holding a value returned by malloc/new or something returned by the address-of operator would magically would evaluate to `false` when converted to `bool`.

Comment: @M.M: as well as `new` (e.g. in `new (std::nothrow)`)

Comment: "and despite itself being a valid pointer" -- `nullptr` is not a pointer and cannot be dereferenced. It can be implicitly converted to a pointer type, and after that dereferencing it results in UB, but `nullptr` itself, no.