# should a destructor be included with a pointer using automatic storage?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

When I create a class, include a pointer in it, and create an object in automatic storage, should I include a destructor in the class? (is it necessary to free the space in the memory?)
Example:

```
class Node{
    char *Name;
    int age;
    Node(char *n = 0, int a = 0) {
        name = strdup(n);
        age = a;
    }
    ~Node(){
        if (name != 0)
            delete(name);
    }
}

Node node1("Roger",20);
```

Comment: In this case, you should be using `std::string` and then no need for any pointers.

Comment: I recommend replacing those `0`s with `NULL` or `nullptr` for readability and to remain in line with convention.

Comment: Write a destructor when you use low level resource allocation such as `malloc` or `new`. However you should almost never use either. In particular, if you need a string, use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is mandatory to avoid memory leaks. It doesn't matter if you are using a class or something else. It's important what `strdup` says. But you must not use `delete`, instead use `free`. The memory in `strdup` is created by using `malloc`, not `new`.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html

> **strdup - duplicate a string**
>
> The returned pointer can be passed to **free()**. A null pointer is
>   returned if the new string cannot be created.

P.S. Don't miss `const` in your declaration of `char *n`, otherwise the caller might expect the string is modified and a simple-string literal cannot be passed without a warning.

P.S.2: Prefer using `nullptr` instead of `0`. This has been discussed several times on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr).

Answer (score 4):

> is it necessary to free the space in the memory?

Yes, it's essential to avoid memory leaks.

Anyway you must use [`free(name);`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) in your example, since `strdup()` is a pure C function, and uses the `malloc()` function to allocate the memory for the copy returned.

---

Also, you should avoid managing raw pointers yourself in C++. Either use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), or [standard C++ containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), or for your specific case simply [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Raw pointers don't go well with, respectively complicate, implementing the [Rule of Three (5/zero)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

If you have something allocated from a C-style interface, you can always use a smart pointer, and provide a custom deleter function, that actually uses the appropriate `free()` call.

Comment: @downvoters care to explain what's wrong with my answer here please? I can't see anything wrong? I'd suppose it was just a _tactical reason_ or what?

Answer (score 2):

If your class has a pointer that points to memory that is allocated with `new` \ `new[]` \ `malloc()` then you need to implement the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

That said, instead of using a raw `char *` and manual memory management, use a [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.  you can still get a `const char*` out of it if you need it for other functions but it fully self managed container.  With it you would not need to provide a copy constructor or destructor as the default ones provided by the compiler will work.