# Struct init with 0

Tags: c++, struct

I have struct:

```
struct stek
{
char value;
struct stek *next; 
};
```

Why i can init this like this:

```
stek *p = 0;
```

What this mean? Why zero?

Comment: How would we know why you decided to init your pointer with 0?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr

Comment: What do you know about pointers? What research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr;**
Because 0 is a valid memory address.

---

Since pointers point to memory locations, the expression is valid and `p` points to memory address 0

Answer (score 1):

Here `0` means `NULL`. In prior C++11, `0` can be used as `NULL` which is pretty ambiguous sometimes. Currently C++ has `nullptr` which makes more sense.

Read more about *difference between NULL and nullptr*.