# c++ initializing Error

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I want to declare a class for Coordinates and I try this codes:

> Coordinate.h:
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned short Short;
> class Coordinate
> {
> private :
>   Short _row;
>   Short _col;
> public:
>   Coordinate(Short row, Short col);
>   bool operator ==(const Coordinate* other);
> };
> ```
>
> Coordinate.cpp:
>
> ```
> #include "Coordinate.h"
>
> Coordinate::Coordinate(Short row, Short col)
>   : _row(row) , _col(col){}
>
> bool Coordinate::operator== (const Coordinate* other)
> {
>   if (other == NULL || this == NULL)
>       return false;
>   if (this == other)
>       return true;
>   if (other->_row != this->_row || other->_col != this->_col)
>       return false;
>   return true;
> }
> ```
>
> Main.cpp :
>
> ```
> #include "Coordinate.h"
> int main()
> {
>   Coordinate a( 2,2 );
> }
> ```

But visual studio 2015 returns this errors:

- Error    C2079   'a' uses undefined class 'Coordinate'
- Error    C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to
  'int'

Comment: How would `this==NULL` ever be true?

Comment: There is no `initializer_list` shown. An `std::initializer_list` is created when you instantiate an object using braced initialization syntax.

Comment: `this == NULL` is true when somebody writes something like ((Coordinate*)NULL) , you can test it @tadman .

Comment: @JohnZeng So in other words, when taking the express train to Undefined Behaviour Town.

Comment: [Beware of the underscore prefix.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 4):

Fix your typo in:

```
#include "Coordinate.h"
int main()
{
  Coodinate a( 2,2 );
}
```

`Coodinate` should be `Coordinate`.

Comment: @Alireza Can you show us the new compiler output to see the errors? It compiles fine on my system (Had to change NULL to 0 though for some reason).

Comment: In C++, you [should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13816448/1848578).

Answer (score 0):

The first error is due to misspelled Coo**r**dinate. Might also fix the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `undefined` means that the compiler can not find the `Coordinate.cpp` file. Have you checked about your project setting that makes the linker link the `Coordinate.cpp` file into your execute file?