# flatten a singly linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, singly-linked-list

I have this tree structure, where each node has a `next` and `child` pointer. I am trying to flatten such a tree to a linked list where each node only uses the `next` pointer.

Example input:

```
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6
            |
            V 
            7 --> 8 -- > 9 --> 10
                  |
                  V
                  11 --> 12
```

Expected output:

```
  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12
```

This is my code:

```cpp
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* child;

    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
        next = NULL;
        child = NULL;
    }
};

ListNode* flatten(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode *temp = head, *r = NULL;
    while (temp) {
        if (temp->child) {
            r = temp->next;
            temp->next = flatten(temp->child);
        }
        if (!temp->next && r) {
            temp->next = r;
            r = NULL;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

### Problem

When I provide it the example input, my code gets into infinite recursion.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: When one picks a tag, one is supposed to read the tag description. Have you read for which questions the tag [tag:dsa] is used?

Comment: That first linked list sure looks like a tree to me...

Comment: Tell me what tag to use then

Comment: @VamsiKrishna *Tell me what tag to use then* -- The `dsa` tag clearly states what it is supposed to be used for, but you went ahead and used it for "Data Structures and Algorithms".   By using the wrong tag, persons who are subscribed to the `dsa` tag for `Digital Signature Algorithm` questions are getting spammed with data structures questions.

Comment: Why do you have `struct ListNode* next;`?  Where are you learning this non-idiomatic C++ style from?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You may find it helpful to print the data structure for the before & after flatten, and maybe while in the process of flattening. `void print(ListNode const* p, ostream& out = cout, string const& indent = "") { while(p) { out << indent << p->val << (p->child ? " +children" : "") << (p->next ? "" : " ->⦰") << "\n"; if (p->child) print(p->child, out, indent + "| "); p = p->next; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not get into infinite recursion, but into an infinite loop.

There are these issues:

- The `child` pointers are never cleared to `nullptr`, and so you get nodes that have both their `child` and `next` pointing to the same node. As you also link back tail nodes to nodes in upper "levels", this eventually leads to revisits of the same `child` nodes over and over again. Things would not get into such cycles if you would clear `child` pointers with `temp->child = nullptr;` right after the recursive call comes back.
- Although `r` saves a pointer to be reused later, there is no provision for when multiple nodes in the same "horizontal" list have a non-null `child` pointer: your loop can only remember one of them in `r`, and so you will lose information.
- The logic gives precedence to linking child lists, coming back to the "calling" list after child lists have been wired into the current list. Yet your desired output gives precedence to the `next` lists, wanting to put child nodes *after* those. I'll assume this part of the code is wrong, and your description of the expected output is right.

You can do this without recursion by just keeping track of the current *tail* of the part of the list that is being flattened, while the temporary pointer walks behind it to move and clean up the `child` pointers it encounters on its way.

```cpp
ListNode* getTail(ListNode* head) { // Assumes non-null argument
    while (head->next) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    return head;
}

ListNode* flatten(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode *tail = getTail(head);
    for (ListNode *node = head; node; node = node->next) {
        tail->next = node->child;
        tail = getTail(tail);
        node->child = nullptr;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but in C++:

- you should not use `NULL` [but `nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13816385/5459839)
- `struct ListNode` can just be `ListNode`
- You can use the shorter [Member Initializer List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/5459839) syntax for your constructor.

So:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode* next = nullptr;
    ListNode* child = nullptr;

    ListNode(int x): val(x) {}
}
```

Finally, `flatten` will always return the argument given to it, so you could consider making it a void function.