# Specializing both true and false for bool

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Why does the C++ allow specialization of a type for *both* `true` and `false` parameters?

```
template<bool> struct omg { /* can't access anything declared here */ };
template<> struct omg<true> { };
template<> struct omg<false> { };
```

Is there any situation in which this is meaningful/useful?

Comment: Perhaps because forbidding it would require extra work and a more  complicated language definition.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'm tempted to say so too, but I thought the same thing of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665349) and yet the answer was a convincing no.

Comment: Nothing requires you to define the primary template, you can do `template<bool> struct omg;` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is no such situation. But standard have no any restricts to template non-type parameters, that are suitable to conditions. By the way, it such restriction were, it should be for all types. It will not be correct to do something like

```
enum A { first, second };

template<A> struct omg {};
template<> struct omg<first> {};
template<> struct omg<second> {};
```

and this is too complicated, IMHO.